# Add a widget to a static front page

Tags: widgets

I'm using [a premium theme, which I purchased](http://themeforest.net/item/simpolio-fullscreen-portfolio-blog-wp-theme/397050) and would like to add a social widget to the static front page. I've made a static page with a image slider my home page.

An example of the page [can be found here](http://www.dannyhouseofficial.com/home-with-slider/).

How do I go about adding a social widget to this page?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is _a social widget?_ Please clarify your question.

Comment: There are several plugins that would enable you to do this, [Widgets on Pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widgets-on-pages/) is just one that could help.
This approach means no-need to delve into code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add widgets to any page you need to have a dynamic sidebar configured. Whether or not you have a dynamic sidebar that is visible from your home page depends on the theme.

If you don't, you can initialize a new sidebar by using the **register_sidebar()** function in your functions.php file (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar)

And then use the id of the sidebar in the **dynamic_sidebar()** function (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) where you want the widget to appear on your homepage (home.php or index.php).

Then you just need to goto Appearance -> Widgets in the backend, and add your widget to your new sidebar.